# Writing $\alpha = \sqrt[p]{2}$ as a polynomial in $g(\alpha)$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

For a prime $p$, let $\alpha = \sqrt[p]{2}$. Let $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial of degree < $p$.

To prove: $\alpha$ can be written as a polynomial in $g(\alpha)$ with rational coefficients. Also show that if $p$ is not prime then this fails, by using $\sqrt[4]{2}$.

First of all, what is the question asking? Suppose $g(x) = g_n x^n + \cdots + g_1 x + g_0$, where the $g_i \in \mathbb{Q}$, where $n < p$. Am I supposed to demonstrate that I can write
$$ \sqrt[p]{2} = p_k(g_n (\sqrt[p]{2})^n + \cdots + g_1 (\sqrt[p]{2}) + g_0)^k + \cdots + p_1(g_n (\sqrt[p]{2})^n + \cdots + g_1 (\sqrt[p]{2}) + g_0) + p_0 $$
where the $p_i \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 3):

The question is asking that you demonstrate the existence of rational constants, $\lambda_0,\cdots,\lambda_{p-1}$ such that, once you call $\gamma=g(\alpha)$, you can write $\alpha=\sum_{0\le i<p}\lambda_i\gamma^i$.

My hint to you: you want to use what you know of field theory, in particular that there is no field between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[p]2\,)$. I don’t recommend outlining how to find the lambdas, though it’s easy enough.

**Addendum**

I guess you haven’t had much field theory. The important facts are, first, that the field extension degree $[\Bbb Q(2^{1/p}):\Bbb Q]=p$, because as you have noted, you have a basis $\{1,2^{1/p},2^{2/p},\dots,2^{(p-1)/p}\}$; and second, that for fields $E\subset F\subset K$, you have multiplicativity: $[K:E]=[K:F][F:E]$. Can you take it from there? (And: don’t look at $g$, look at $\gamma=g(\alpha)$.)

Comment: So I've been wrestling with this for quite a while now, but don't seem to be getting anywhere. I see that the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[p]{2}$ is degree $p$, while $g$ has degree strictly less than $p$. Also, I see that if $p$ is not prime, then the basis $\{a_0, a_1 2^{1/p}, a_2 ^{2/p}, \ldots, 2^{(p - 1)/p}\}$ for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$ will include some $2^{j/p}$ for some divisor $j$ of $p$, so that $\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[j]{2}) \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$. But I still don't quite see what's going on.

Comment: Try it now, @Junglemath .

Comment: You're right, I have not had much field theory (nor much of anything else), but I did know that the degree of the extension is $p$ and about the multiplicativity of degrees of extensions. But I can't say much about this, except that if $q < p$ for $q \geq 2$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[q]{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$ by the multiplicativity property. I should be able to say something about $g(\alpha)$ but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: There is no $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[q]2\,)$ here, @Junglemath . Forget about that. How big is $\Bbb Q(\gamma)$? There are no fields between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$. Therefore, $\Bbb Q(\gamma)=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, and in particular is of degree $p$ over $\Bbb Q$. In particular, $\alpha\in\Bbb Q(\gamma)$, and is a $\Bbb Q$-linear combination of the powers of $\gamma$. End of story.